# LocationManager giving 2 different values for Lat and Long for same location

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

In my UI I am using the code

```
   // getting location service
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

and them I am getting the Location as

```
location =  locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

And in my BroadcastReceiver I am getting Location as

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Location location = (Location)bundle.get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
```

I am getting 2 different Latitudes (and longitudes) for the same location using these 2 methods.

Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE!!!
I just found out something very interesting.

On My Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 -

From UI  - LAT=18.5798001 & LONG=73.7363223 and from broadcast receiver LAT=18.5770622 & LONG=73.7389527 And **DISTANCE Between 2 locations is 420 Meters**

On My MOTO E

From UI  - LAT=18.5798001 & LONG=73.7363223 and from broadcast receiver LAT=18.5771489 & LONG=73.7391201 And **DISTANCE Between 2 locations is about 5 Meters**

In my code I have calculations based on distance. They are working perfectly on MOTO E, but they go haywire on Nexus 4 & Nexus 7!

So does it mean getting Latitude and Longitude is device dependent?? How is that possible? I am totally confused.

Comment: no.. the last know location is the location tat was last known, and as the location changed you got the new location. You should use the mLocationManager location when u receive it as it is the current locaiton

Comment: Panther - Even I thought that may be if I get the Location exactly the same way both in UI and BroadcastReceiver I will get the same Lats/Longs. I did that, got location using the exact same code in BroadcastReceiver as I have in UI. It still shows different Lats and Longs for the same location.

Comment: How much do they differ?

Comment: From UI -- LAT=18.5798001 & LONG=73.7363223 and from broadcast receiver LAT=18.5770622 & LONG=73.7389527... And I have not moved an inch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I guess I cracked it.

The issue was difference in how I was accessing the lats and longs in UI and BroadcastReceiver.

In the UI, since I had to show addresses, I used Geocoder to do reverse geocoding. I got the Address objects using the getFromLocation() method, I used the these objects to retrieve my lats and long to store in my data store (which was the mistake!)

In the BroadcastReceiver I used the Location object to get the lats and longs.

The Geocoder changes lats and longs based on the actual addresses retrieved using the lats and longs which were supplied in the getFromLocation() method (since it searches all the nearby addresses and returns the best matches). So basically lats and longs in the Address objects are "best guesses" and belonging to addresses that mathched.

So obviously I was having issues when I compared the lats and longs stored in UI with Lats and Longs I was getting in BroadcastRececiver.

Now my app is working great both on Moto and Nexus devices.

However this still doesnt answer one question. How was Moto E able to resolve the lats and longs from reverse geocoding almost accurately?!! hmmmm...! Anyway, issues is resolved for me.